# Import from node_modules into Svelte

Tags: ionic-framework, node-modules, svelte, rollupjs

Let me preface this by saying my knowledge of node apps and javascript is very limited, all my programming knowledge comes from a python data analyst background.

So, I am trying to learn frontend and build an app in [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/). I will serve this app with another backend so I will not be using [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/). I am also using [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) for my UI framework. I will probably use [Routify](https://www.routify.dev/) for routing but this is beyond the scope of this question. Also, I know svelte isn't officially supported by Ionic but i'm not interested in using another framework.

The simple method would be to include the Ionic CDN in the svelte index.html. However, I would like to keep my files in one place when I build the final app and not require a CDN or even possibly a network connection if I decide to use [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) to build for mobile devices. So, I'm not sure how to proceed. I would like to bundle Ionic ([Ionic/Core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/core) - [IonicIcons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionicons)) with the default JS and CSS bundles that svelte builds using [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/). Googling around a bit iv'e discovered I apparently need to use something called "rollup-plugin-css-only" to bundle the CSS and somehow include the JS files in commonjs in the "rollup.config.js". I tried adding the path to the JS files to commonjs but I couldn't see any changes to the bundled JS the svelte outputs. I also have no idea how to use add the css or use "rollup-plugin-css-only". Instructions and explanations iv'e found haven't been very helpful.

So, in summary... I'm trying to bundle [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) into my svelte project without using a CDN and haven't figured out how too do it yet. I also may not be understanding this workflow correctly so let me know if I got something wrong. I just need an explanation or example of Ionic bundled in a svelte app. I would also like to mention that the workflow I am looking to accomplish will also allow custom themes in Ionic with the CSS processing.

Comment: I found this git feature request https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/issues/446 with comments that has one explanation but it must be using an older version of Ionic because I can't get it to work.

Comment: Doesn't the repo linked in this reply show exactly how to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59451332

Comment: It appears to be using a CDN yet. Check it's index.html https://github.com/Tommertom/svelte-ionic-app/blob/master/src/index.html I'm not sure exactly what's going on there. It may be using a combination of both to make all features load and work smoothly. I need it to be all build with sources from the node module and not use any external CDN. Also, I need to be able to do css theming as well.